What is the difference between interstellar space & intergalactic space?
What would be tangible differences to observe or feel between interstellar and intergalactic space?

Intergalactic space is even more empty... see this question on astronomy SE: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/47279/what-are-the-differences-between-intergalactic-medium-interstellar-medium-and-i ... 1/cm³ compared to 1/m³

I wrote (and learned) a bit about the nature of and challenges of interstellar spaceflight in this answer. Intergalactic spaceflight is not much of a topic in Space Exploration SE, I wonder if migration of this question to Astronomy SE might be appropriate?

Intergalactic space is at an even harder vacuum than interstellar space which itself is an extremely hard vacuum.
There are some locations in intergalactic space in some of the great voids that are so far from any galaxies that anyone who somehow got there would not be able to see anything at all (without a telescope) simply blackness in every direction.
The main difference is the degree of remoteness from anything made of matter bar a few hydrogen molecules.
